# Common layout in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to WPF an creating a application where I want to make a generic layout which could  be applied for all windows.I want few buttons and window properties to be comman on all windows.

Please help if this is possible.I am unable to find any link or source where this sort of functionality is explained.

### Many Thanks.

*****Edit****

I am using this code which shows a button on window.I dont want to write it on all windows.I want to place in base/parent so that it appears on all windows which i add to project and inherit from the base/parent class.

But How? I have got very little idea.Any help is appreciated.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Content="settings" Name="Settings" Click="Settings_Click" />
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cupcake}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="test" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

Comment: If I try to create a WPF window user control can I host it in other window?if yes,please share how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a common theme for the whole application you should look in the direction of Styles and Shared Resources, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx

Or you can use ready-made Themes, like here http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/

**EDIT**

You can achieve this by moving the common controls which should be used in all windows to a separate UserControl. So then you will have smth like this:

**UserControl**

```
  <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="settings" Name="Settings"  />
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="test" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Then to all the windows where you need these controls you should add this control, like this:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="myCtrl"></local:UserControl1>
```

where **local** is the namespace where the UserControl1 is defined.

Comment: Is it possible to implement events(button_click etc) using Styles/Resources ? I am able to implement for window properties but what about events?

Comment: Styles are not supposed to interfere with the behavior of your window. I'm not sure i got your question right, but if you need common view exactly (without overriding behavior), you can implement all your events the way you did it before.

Comment: @PankajBhatia I added some code, hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for you help so far, just one question I hope you could tell-   
If I try to create a WPF window user control can I host it in other window?if yes,please share how to do it.

Comment: Yes, the idea of UserControl is that any other window of your application can host it. You just need to define your UserControl the way I showed you in my code example. If you need further explanation, please ask.

Comment: The user control i want to create is it self a window.So if I create such control then would i be able to host it in any window?I m not sure if this correct approach but If it is possible then only I shud proceed further..

Comment: Well, basically a UserControl is regarded as a set of controls which you want to reuse in different windows. So you create a UserControl with the controls you need, and then add it to all your windows,you don't need a whole window as a UserControl.

Comment: Thanks a lot!lot more question still to come in future too!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it..  there is a term called **UserControl** you have to write your own UserControl.

For basic how to write re-usable UserControl. check the [given link](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html)

Its not the control you want.. but you can get an idea how to write UserControl.. :)